# subprocess error messages in python

Tags: python, subprocess

```
x = open('data.txt', 'a')
g = open('graphing_data.txt', 'a')
subprocess.call(['sfit4Layer0.py', '-bv5', '-fh']) # only need to do this once
with open('filenames.txt', 'r') as r:
    for line in r:
        opusfile = line.strip()
        subprocess.call(['ckopus', '-FSNGC', '-SFL0', '-u6', opusfile])
        subprocess.call(['sfit4Layer0.py', '-bv5', '-fp'])
        subprocess.call(['sfit4Layer0.py', '-bv5', '-fs'])
        # now summary file is produced so must write in summary file code here

        for infile in glob.glob(os.path.join(road, 'summary*')):
            #write data from summary to data.txt and graphing_data.txt

x.close()
g.close()
```

I have a program that requires one to write the commands found in the `subprocess.call` lines above into the terminal to process data files, so I figured I would write a program to automate this (I have over 100 data files). My program references filenames.txt with a list of filenames and reads them in as opusfile to execute with the first command. It seems to process the first file correctly and then I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "template.py", line 24, in <module>
    subprocess.call(['ckopus', '-FSNGC', '-SFL0', '-u6', opusfile])
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I have tried understanding the subprocess module but it is somewhat confusing to me, if anybody has tips or a link to a solid tutorial that would be great - I am fairly new at Python.

Comment: As the error states there is no file with thename of the content of `opusfile`

Comment: It seems to me like `opusfile` could not be found. Perhaps the path is wrong? Have you checked the value of `opusfile`?

Comment: opusfile contains the filenames which is what sfit4 needs, it doesn't need the path and I changed the path in my bash profile. why did it work for the first one but then not the next? it also works if I hard-code in the filename.